# Notepad++ Changebar

Tags: notepad++, plugins, productivity

Notepad++ used to have a changebar (similar to the Microsoft code editor in Visual Studio) that would change color, if the line of text was changed.  It was taken out some time ago, but I really liked it.

Is there a plugin (or option) that will re-enable this feature?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [LocationNav](http://sourceforge.net/projects/locationnav/) plugin lets the user mark changed lines in different ways, e.g. highlight, underline and symbol (rectangle, roundrect, circle, triangle and arrow). (In fact, I find this feature more useful than its original purpose of returning to lines the cursor previously moved onto!)

Comment: +1 This seems to work pretty well so far (testing with NPP 6.1.8).  I've been looking for a replacement for (or update to) the ChangeMarkers plugin by aathell (which causes NPP to hang/crash in some cases) for years... this might do the trick if it's reliable.

Comment: Thanks, and you're welcome! FYI, I found a very frustrating incompatibility with the Compare plugin: Each time I do a compare, the marking method changes to highlighting the entire line, whereas I prefer to mark changes with a rectangle (or "changebar", as in Change Markers). Worse, selecting "Mark with rect" does not fix it; I need to select a different method, e.g. "Mark with circle" then reselect "Mark with rect".

Answer (score 1):

You can use this [plugin (Change Markers)](http://cid-71a486ea08eb407c.skydrive.live.com/browse.aspx/.Public/NppPluginIface).

This is a pretty good list of [Notepad++ plugins](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/notepad-plus/index.php?title=Plugin_Central)

Comment: Thanks, but the Change Markers plugin is not not compatible with the latest version of Notepad++.

Answer (score 1):

You may have something like [Change Markers](http://cid-71a486ea08eb407c.skydrive.live.com/browse.aspx/.Public/NppPluginIface), a [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) plugin, in mind. It's listed on the Notepad++ [plugins page](https://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/notepad-plus/index.php?title=Plugin_Central#C).

Comment: Thanks, but the Change Markers plugin is not not compatible with the latest version of Notepad++.

Comment: I just installed the Unicode plugin w/ Notepad++ 5.7 (sorry, I should have tried it before posting earlier answer), and it seems to work for me. I tried it on several files and yellow bars appear in the left margin as I make changes to the file. When I save the file, the bars all turn green. I *did* have to restart Npp after enabling the plugin. (I think it's pretty cool, actually. I'm going to leave it in.)

Comment: Bill, I just did the exact same thing and was getting on here to post the same apology. You and I are on some kind of uncanny time cycle.

I also found an article about Change Marker and it said that because of known issues of stability, it has been taken out of the most recent versions. Depending on your system setup, it either works fine, or doesn't at all.

The author of the plugin said he's working on a new version, but that was several months ago. So I'm not exactly sure when a new version is expected to be released.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you get in touch with the maintainer of the [Change Markers plugin](http://cid-71a486ea08eb407c.skydrive.live.com/browse.aspx/.Public/NppPluginIface)?

His email address as given in the [Directory for Notepad++ plugins](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/notepad-plus/index.php?title=Plugin_Central#C) is given as:
`aathell [at] users [dot] sourceforge [dot] net`

Comment: Unfortunately, he is apparently not responding to emails.